# Incorrect date in moment.js getters

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

**EDIT: NB:** As pointed out in the accepted answer from Zohaib Ijaz `month` gives the 0-11 value for the month but the second problem is `day`. `day` gives a numeric representation of day of the week ie 0 = sunday, 1 = tuesday. If you want to get the 1-31 you need `date`.

OK I think this must be a super dumb question but I just cannot see it. Today is 11th November 2019

```
  var day = moment().get('day');
  var month = moment().get('month');
  var year = moment().get('year');

  var dateSet = month+"/"+day+"/"+year;
  console.log(dateSet);
```

and I get back: `10/01/2019`!

I tried the functional getter of `var day = moment().day();` etc. and same again.

I am trying to get today's date and the date in three months times for a datepicker. Greatful for an explanation of this and extremely grateful for a pointer as how to do the +3 months which I tried `moment().plus(3,"months")` which did not work.

I am extremely tired but I am pretty sure at one stage this was giving the right date. What could possibly have changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moment().month()` or `moment().get('month')` will return month from `0` as `January` to `11` as `December`. So if you want to create date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format, user moment().format(format_string). Or add 1 in month while creating your date string. I would suggest to use format and go through moment docs first so you have better idea what it provides out of the box.

See docs
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/get/

> moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY')

Comment: @Zohaib_Ijaz - thank you, thank you, thank you! Fudged it in a very simple way. I am just trying to get a datepicker working and looks like you have given me the tools. I had searched through the docs but somehow missed it. The numeric dates being 0-11 is just plain weird. I know we talk about arrays that way but I have not seen 0-11 in any other date thingmy. Once again آپ کا شکریہ looking good here. Steve

Comment: @BeNice You are welcome. FYI, week days have same behaviour, `0 - 6` so keep in mind. خوش رہو

Comment: I forgot to say `date` gives the right/normal number.